# Builds on TFS take ages when restoring Nuget packages

Tags: tfs, nuget, tfsbuild, nuget-package

When I build my solution on visualstudio.com it takes absolutely ages. 15 minutes to build and test. Considering we only get 60 minutes of free build time that's far too long.

Nearly all the build time is restoring Nuget packages.

My build is configured to not clean down the source every time so in theory the packages shouldn't need downloading every time but because it's hosted maybe that setting is irrelevant.

Is anyone else seeing this issue? What's the recommended way to handle nuget packages when using visualstudio.com? I'm tempted to add the packages to source control so they don't have to be downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you do a build in the elastic build services you get a new server. This server is used for your build and then destroyed. You will need to get the NuGet packages every time.

I would recommend that you create an Azure VM and run your custom build in there. This will not take time from your 60 minutes and as a 'static' server it will cache the packages...

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Is that just the way it is for Nuget and VisualStudio.com then? That makes their build service a bit rubbish for anything other than trivial projects.

Comment: If you have tones of NuGet packages you will need to restore them. I would head over to http://visualstudio.uservoice.com and vote for an alternative.